# Typeset Unicode Control Pictures

Tags: pdftex, unicode

I have a specific need for typesetting the [Unicode Control Pictures](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2400). Unfortunately, I only have access to pdfTeX. Is there any way to insert these symbols?

Comment: They are just diagonal series of letters so you could use picture environment (or tikz or ....) and make macros for each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could produce macros for each, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Znul{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\tiny\sffamily
\put(0,6){N}
\put(4,3){U}
\put(7,0){L}
\end{picture}}
\newcommand\Zsoh{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\tiny\sffamily
\put(0,6){S}
\put(4,3){O}
\put(7,0){H}
\end{picture}}

\begin{document}

null is \Znul,
start of heading is \Zsoh,
rest are left as an excercise for the reader.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not sth like `\newcommand\ZZ[3]{\begin{picture}(10,10)
\tiny\sffamily
\put(0,6){#1}
\put(4,3){#2}
\put(7,0){#3}
\end{picture}}`?

Comment: @marmot partly as that is part of the "exercise for the reader" and partly as (although the numbers are the same here) I tweaked each position by eye and different letters may want different values.